# Quel est le sens de « cancan » dans « French Cancan » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques, spectacle

Quel est le sens de *cancan* dans *French Cancan* ? Est-ce un mot anglais ou bien français ? Est-ce un diminutif ou un nom propre ?

Comment: Voir [cancan](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/cancan) deuxième sens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Une chose est sûre, le "Cancan" de French Cancan est un mot français désignant la danse d'origine dont est issue le French Cancan, qui en est la version édulcorée (comprendre avec culottes fermées), à l'origine, les danseuses de cancan portait jupe et culotte fendue ce qui produisait un effet pour le moins érotique à chaque levé de jambe.

Plusieurs origines possibles à ce "cancan" sont possibles :

1. D'après [le dictionnaire de la danse de Desrat](http://books.google.fr/books?id=ZLsBs7et5dMC&lpg=PA72&vq=cancan&hl=fr&pg=PA72#v=snippet&q=cancan&f=falsehttp://books.google.fr/books?id=ZLsBs7et5dMC&lpg=PA72&vq=cancan&hl=fr&pg=PA72#v=snippet&q=cancan&f=false) l'origine de la danse "Cancan" remonterait en 1830. Sur l'étymologie du mot, il est moins catégorique et cite 2 origines possible :

   - le "cancan" serait une variante du cri du canard "coin-coin" (sans doute lié à la manière de bouger des danseurs pouvant rappeler la démarche d'un canard)
   - le "cancan" serait relatif à de longues discussions pouvant avoir lieu autour
2. D'après [les Études de philologie comparée sur l'argot de Francisque Michel](http://books.google.fr/books?id=n28RAAAAIAAJ&vq=cancan&hl=fr&pg=PA89#v=snippet&q=cancan&f=false), à nouveau 2 origines possibles :

   - le "cancan" serait nommé ainsi parce que les danseurs imitaient la démarche et le cri de l'oie
   - le sens de "cancan" serait lié au bruit des participants comme dans l'expression *"faire un grand cancan de quelque chose"* = *"faire beaucoup de bruit pour rien"*

Answer (score 1):

J'ai trouvé un lien sur l'[origine de *cancan*](http://www.ptidico.com/definition/cancan.htm#acad1986).

Mais le Robert est plus précis :

> **cancan** : 1829, du nom enfantin du canard : "Quadrille populaire excentrique et tapageur. *le cancan de Montmartre*"
>
> **french cancan** : en 1953 ajout du mot anglais french : "*Danse constituant le spectacle traditionnel des bals publics du Montmartre 1900, encore pratiqué dans certains cabarets.*"

Je retiendrai aussi le scandale (d'où le *cancan*) typiquement français que suscitait ces danseuses dévergondées à l'époque où la bourgeoisie s'encanaillait au pied de la butte.
Il faut rappeler que le quartier de [Montmartre](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montmartre) a un statut particulier dans la ville de Paris.